# Ways to form pairs of 2n people

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Suppose we have $2n$ people and we want to make $n$ ordered pairs of these $2n$ people. So we can chose $2$ people for the first pair in ${2n\choose2}$ ways, then we are left with $2n-2$ people and we can chose $2$ of them for the second pair in ${2n-2\choose2}$ ways and so on. So the number of ways of forming $n$ ordered pairs of $2n$ people is then $${2n\choose2}{2n-2\choose2}....{2\choose2}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}$$. But we can also proceed like this : We first choose $n$ people from those $2n$ people in ${2n\choose n}$ ways, then we get two groups of $n$ people each and then we can make pairs among them in $n!$ ways and so the total number of ways of forming $n$ ordered pairs of $2n$ people is $$\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}n!=\frac{(2n)!}{n!}$$. But these two answers are different?

Comment: The actual computation is $~\displaystyle \frac{(2n)!}{2^n \times n!}.~$  The first method is **almost** correct, and simply overlooks the need for the over-counting adjustment factor of $~\dfrac{1}{n!}~$ to adjust for the fact that for each distinct collection of $~n~$ pairs, there are $~n!~$ ways that the $~n~$ pairs can be ordered.  Your first method would therefore over count each distinct collection of $~n~$ pairs by a factor of $~(n!).$

Comment: The OP need ordered pairs, so shouldn't the answer be the second one? @user2661923

Comment: @DS Yes good catch.  The combination of my careless reading of the posting's first sentence, plus my focusing on the first method used by the OP (i.e. original poster) caused me to totally overlook that.  So, my first comment only applies if you are sampling without replacement to form unordered sets, each of size $~2,~$ rather than ordered pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example should make it clear:
Say $n=2$. The $2n$ things are $A,B,C,D$. For the first case, you get $6$ ways. These are
 $AB,CD$
 $AC,BD$
 $AD,BC$
 *and*
 $CD,AB$
 $BD,AC$
 $BC,AD$. If you increase $n$, (for $n=3$, it's $90$ ways) you will observe that this method *permutes* the group of pairs, i.e, it counts $AB,CD$ and $CD,AB$ as different cases. However, it counts $AB,DC$ and $AB,CD$ as the same.
In the second case, you get $12$ cases. They are
 $AC,BD$
 $AD,BC$
 $AB,CD$
 $AD,CB$
 $BA,CD$
 $BD,CA$
 $AC,DB$
 $AB,DC$
 $BA,DC$
 $BC,DA$
 $CB,DA$
 $CA,DB$. If you increase $n$ (for $n=3$ there are $120$ ways) you will observe that this method *does not permute* the group pairs, i.e $AD,BC$ and $BC,AD$ are the same, but it counts $BC,AD$ and $BC,DA$ as different.

Now, can you see which formula is appropriate for you? Ordered pair means $AB,CD$ and $BA,DC$ are different. Your question has no mention of the order of the pairs, meaning $AB,CD$ and $CD,AB$ are same.

---

We can go from the formula of method 1 to that of method 2:

- Method 1 counts $AB,CD,EF$ and $AB,EF,CD$ as different but method 2 does not. S divide by $n!$ to get $\frac{(2n)!}{n!2^n}$.
- Method 1 counts $AB,CD,EF$ and $BA,DC,EF$ as same, but method 2 does not. So, multiply by $2^n$ (you flip a coin $n$ times, if the $k$th toss is heads, you write a pair in alphabetical order, say $AC$, and if it's tails you write it in non-alphabetical order, say $CA$) to get $\frac{(2n)!}{n!}$.

Comment: There's a typo in the first example - you have BD,AB for (I think) BD,AC. I tried to edit but the minimum character limit is preventing me.

Comment: Good catch @LizWeir

Answer (score 2):

Your first answer corresponds to picking $n$ pairs, respecting the order (so 1st pair, 2nd pair, ...) where there is no order in the individual pairs.

Your second answer corresponds to picking $n$ pairs without having an order, where there is an order in each individual pair (first group and second group). Since you stated that you want "$n$ ordered pairs of these $2n$ people", this is probably the answer you are looking for.

You can get from your first answer to your second by first introducing an order to each individual pair (for $n$ pairs this scales the number of possibilities by $2^n$) and then discarding the order of the pairs (for $n$ pairs this means dividing by $n!$).

Comment: Then the total number of ways of forming $n$ ordered pairs where the pairs are also ordered and the individual pairs are also ordered is $(2n)!$?

Comment: @user671269 that's right.

Comment: @user671269 You can think of it like so: Line up the 2n people, then every two consecutive people make an ordered pair (so you have (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6) and so on).

Comment: @VegaVen2ra here is a [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your future posts.

Comment: @DS Thank you! :)